# How to alias ENTER key with a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can we alias Enter key with a command so that when I press enter at the prompt the command should be executed. for example when I press enter at the prompt, ls command should be executed.

```
abc@def$ 
<output of ls command>

abc@def$
```

So that I can add the alias in .bashrc file.

Thank you..!

Comment: I don't know if you can do this. Even if you can this is a bad idea since every command is interpreted by the shell when you press ENTER. That action already has a meaning. I recommend you not do this, you are radically modifying the default shell behavior.

Answer (score 6):

You can set a prompt command.

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="ls"
```

Comment: Or PROMPT_COMMAND='h=$(fc -l -1); h=${h%% *}; (( h != oh )) || ls; oh=$h'  if you don't want to run ls after every command.

Comment: @sch sometimes it is giving me the output of ls with some other command. can you explain the script so that even I can debug it.

Comment: I've edited Adam's response, let's see if it gets accepted.